# Does an assignment operator in c++ return rvalue or lvalue?

Tags: c++, expression, operator-precedence

Does an assignment operator in c++ returns an rvalue or an lvalue? And if it is an lvalue, which of the two arguments will be incremented here?

```
(a = b)++
```

Comment: Have you tried it? A simple debug message should tell you the answer.

Comment: It works, and it returns lvalue for first argument, but maybe it's undefined or unspecified behavior? Or maybe works only for this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It returns a **lvalue**. Per § 5.17:

> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all
>   group right-to-left. **All require a modifiable lvalue** as their left
>   operand and return an lvalue referring to the left operand.

If those objects have an user-defined operator for assignment, then it depends on implementation and declaration (return type) of the `operator=`.

So normally, after

```
(a = b)++
```

The object `a` will be incremented.