# Order of evaluation with assignment operator

Tags: c++, postfix-operator

Can anyone explain to me why the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int y=3;
    int z = (--y) + (y=10);
    printf("%d \n", z);
}
```

prints out `z=20`? I thought it should be `z=19` instead?

Comment: why not `z=12`  ?

Comment: Why did you think that it should be 19?

Comment: Just to clarify the points made in the duplicate: there is nothing in the C++ Standard that determines whether `(--y)` or `(y=10)` should be evaluated first.

Comment: I could not understand how this code works but this code not depends on initial y value. Always gives the 2y(y is the last y value)

Comment: @OgünBirinci you do not understand how it works simply because it does not work.

Comment: @slava What do you mean by `it does not work'? As in, the code wouldn't compile? Cause I tried and it did.

Comment: @QuangThinhHa unfortunately in C++ the fact that code compiles does not mean it is legal. Read about Undefined Behavior https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub and worst thing that happens with UB - you get result you expected

Comment: @Slava You're right. Is there any specific logic in the output we get. Why we always get 2y result? Is it a random output?. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @OgünBirinci it is quite pointless to discuss why you get particular value when result is garbage. If you are interested you can look into produced assembly, but again it is pointless.

Comment: @OgünBirinci Try `int z = (--y) + (--y);`, maybe that will make the situation clearer. The prefix `--` is equivalent to `y-=1`, and per [specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) the return value is an **an lvalue identifying the left operand after modification**. I think understanding this is the key to your confusion. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19244627/1092820) for a neat example.